# What can be said about characteristics of physical objects and relations among them without using space?

Tags: epistemology, semantics, empiricism, perception

If we start from the premise that all our acquired knowledge of objects comes to us from having seen them in certain relations to other objects in space, how would we be able to describe an object if we took out *space* from the mix?

You wouldn't be able to tell its distinguishing characteristics since it would appear, I am assuming, almost as a 2D figure. Once that is gone, what other characteristics would the object hold, independent of space?

Also, without space, how would you establish the relation between two objects? You can't possibly establish a relation between two things solely on the basis of **time**.

And if you can't put the two objects in *space*(which isn't there any longer), how would you ever be able to make parallels?

Comment: I'm not so sure I buy you premise here. Yes, we gain knowledge from things that are in space and time, but is the knowledge we gain about them a function of their being in "certain relations to other objects in space" in generic terms or is that we perceive them through space? Also, if that's the premise, then isn't the outcome obvious? (we could know nothing without space if the premise is true)

Comment: @virmaior No object can exist independently, at least to our senses. Therefore, our sensory inputs always establish a relation with the surroundings of that object. Imagine a _glass of water_. 
You try to remove everything from your vision except that glass. But you can't imagine it without the existence of space. A lot of what appears to you as its properties come from our notion of space.
And from here comes my question. **If we take out space, what characteristics remain of the object?**

Comment: depending on what is meant by "take out space", then I assume there would no object remaining for physical objects since they are by definition spatial objects. But our knowledge of spatial objects is knowledge of these objects and only for ancillary reasons does it matter what other objects are nearby at the time, which is my point

Comment: @virmaior But if we do not know what surrounds an object, we cannot induce anything about it. And for something to surround an object, there must be _space_. 
So without the notion of space, would our brain ever be able to tell two different objects apart? So you see, it has more importance than just that of providing ancillary footing.

Comment: If there's no space, there's no object to begin with , right?

Comment: @virmaior Precisely what I'm grappling with. But it gets even trickier. Suppose that objects were able to exist without space. And we were able to conceive them. Even then, we wouldn't be able to say anything in regard to some of its characters. 
Take the example of **location**. To pinpoint any object's specific location, we must refer to both _space_ and _time_. If one goes out of the loop, we are helpless.

Comment: Is this question then conceivably answerable in a SE format?

Comment: @virmaior Of course. Being new to the subject of Philosophy, I don't see why my argument couldn't have some inherent flaws. And the presenting of new facts could certainly make me change my opinion. I'd say that's answerable enough.

Comment: "You wouldn't be able to tell its distinguishing characteristics since it would appear, I am assuming, almost as a 2D figure." - could you define what you mean by "if we took out space from the mix" ? Space is tradionally made of 3 dimensions so if you remove it, you have only time left. So the 2D notion seems erroneous to me : That's only removing some of space.

Comment: @user2808054 A very nice observation. What I meant was that without space, we would have no **sense of depth**. Our eyes would only be able to make out an object's physical features but not the relation it holds to space.

Comment: If you take space out of equation, then you will also have to take out space from the concept of perception itself. Our perception system is itself spatial and temporal and this system (or object) is able to perceive other spatial and temporal objects in space. Space is gone then the spatial nature of perception system itself is gone. Think it like this: A person is perceiving object in space and the person itself is in space too. Space is gone what now?

Comment: @SamparkSharma OK thanks I think I'm getting there - you effectively mean a 2D world ? If so could you edit the question to make it more clear what you mean by removing space ? I don't have a definitive answer but it'll probably help others come up with somehting :-)

Comment: @Ankur I am assuming humans and all other things to be **objective truths** that can exist independent of space.

Comment: @user2808054 I'm afraid the question I'm posing is much more multi-layered than that. The essence of my question isn't that of _how we might conceive the nature of objects to have changed if we take space out of the mix_. The question I'm posing is _what characteristics, for us, will it continue to hold and how we could possibly explain its relation to other objects of the like?_.

Comment: Do you have an example of something that is out of space but still in time; and as importantly a philosopher that has questioned this along these lines?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Every single thing exists in time. It's just that you can't pinpoint an object's **location** through it. You'd need its _point in space_ for that. Time, by itself, means nothing. So, does anything exist _in_ time? Probably yes.

Comment: @sharma: I'm struggling to concieve how one can think of objects in time but not in space; usually when someone, for example Plato, concieve of things outside of space and time; it's because they are not subject to *change*; for example the numbers are not, so this is how Plato concieved them; in his philosophy, they never were in space or time; they have never been, nor ever will be an actually existing 'number 5' in this universe; still, we are able to concieve of relationships between numbers.

Comment: If I may offer an example, and see if it meets Sampark's needs, without space I believe you could still experience the "wetness" of water.  You may not know "where the water is," but the qualia of wetness does not have a significant spatial nature, so it can be observed without space relatively undisturbed from our current spatially-aware qualia.

Comment: @ammon: good example ie if I close my eyes so that the world and space disappears, wetness is something I can experience without it being in space.

Comment: @MoziburUllah That isn't exclusive to Philosophy. Physics and many other subjects employ similar workings. If something is **constant**, we can expect it to not change its properties with respect to time and space. That doesn't always mean that it _doesn't exist_ in time and space.


We are only able to 'conceive of relationships between numbers' because we know them to be separate entities. If I ask you to imagine the numbers _5_ and _6_, the two will appear in your mind as separate, having space between them,which is our sole criteria for differentiation. A number can't exist in nothingness.

Comment: @sharma: I'd argue that 'imagining a number' is as though I had written numbers on a page, and imagined them; which goes along with your description.

Comment: @CortAmmon As is made clear from the very first sentence of my question, I refer exclusively to our **knowledge of objects**. Wetness to the other senses would mean nothing without our eyes. We'd know the feeling, but how could we ever say that this _wetness_ comes from something that exists in space? Surely we couldn't infer it from our _sense of touch or smell_.

Comment: @SamparkSharma Ahh, I did not read that fully.  In that case, your question doesn't make sense.  "If we start from the premise that all knowledge of objects comes from their relationship in space, how would we describe objects if we did not have space [or spatial relationships]," has created a strange pattern with a premise that leads its answer.  Instead I think it's meaningful to point out that not all knowledge of objects is actually spatial.  Also worth noting that mathematicians are comfortable with "spatial" relationships in the abstract sense, using something called a "measure."

Comment: It may be worthwhile to better understand what you believe an object "is," and what you believe "spatial" means.  That may help for us making sense of the question better.  When digging into questions like "what can we know without space," it starts to border on behaviors like zen koans, "what is the sound of one hand clapping?"  In the case of the koan, that question is never fully answered.  It's the journey towards an answer that the zen master is looking to help shape.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28948/discussion-on-question-by-sampark-sharma-without-space-what-would-we-know-about).

Comment: @CortAmmon An object's relationship _to_ space and its relationship _in_ space are two very different things. My question has more to deal with the former.

Comment: I may need further clarification on what you believe the difference is between those things, but I think I'm starting to capture something which might be similar to what you mean.  Are you implying a world which, ontologically, has space but which our minds simply have not chosen to map characteristics that we consider, today, to be spatial, like measures and metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's amend the premise by taking "space" out of it:"our acquired knowledge of objects comes to us from having seen them in certain relations to other objects". Space points do not come with labels attached, even when we measure distances they are distances between markings of some sort, not points. And we can easily establish relations between objects without space, say numbers 2 and 17, or even vectors and operators in infinite-dimensional spaces. They are not physical objects of course, and space is around for those, but even physically objects are demarcated by other objects, and their characteristics are contrasted to characteristics of other objects.

Come to think about it there is no space involved in any of it, it is merely kept, and perhaps constructed, as framing. Psychologists established that our visual perception starts with a flat and spotty impression on the retina, which is then filled in and 3-dimensionalized by the brain. Kant even believed that this imposition of flat 3D space is the source of synthetic a priori knowledge which will forever subject our physical theories to 3D Euclidean geometry. As it turned out, even the space of visual perception is slightly hyperbolic.

The idea of empty independent absolute space only came to prominence after Newton, who adopted it because it was the simplest way to express classical mechanics (modern textbooks have to go through a complication of reference frames). Before that relational theory of space was a consensus since Aristotle. Descartes identified space with matter, so that when matter moves the space moves, it does not leave some empty space behind to arrive at a new one. [Leibniz gave the most comprehensive expression of the "ideality of space" in relational theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#6.1). He held that "*(i) a body comes to have the ‘same place’ as another once did, when it comes to stand in the same relations to bodies we ‘suppose’ to be unchanged... (ii) That we can define ‘a place’ to be that which any such two bodies have in common... And finally that (iii) space is all such places taken together. However, he also holds that properties are particular, incapable of being instantiated by more than one individual, even at different times; hence it is impossible for the two bodies to be in literally the same relations to the unchanged bodies. Thus the thing that we take to be the same for the two bodies — the place — is something added by our minds to the situation, and only ideal. As a result, space, which is constructed from these ideal places, is itself ideal: ‘a certain order, wherein the mind conceives the application of relations’*".

When working on general relativity Einstein noticed that if we know gravitational field around a region in space there is no unique way to extend it into that region, but that different extensions are physically equivalent despite assigning different field values to different spacetime points. This came to be called the ["hole argument"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_argument#Einstein.27s_resolution). Einstein concluded from it that individual spacetime points as such are physically meaningless and accepted the relational theory:"*People before me believed that if all the matter in the universe were removed, only space and time would exist. My theory proves that space and time would disappear along with matter.*"

Comment: I am, to a good extent, satisfied with what you are saying. The answer seems to lie in the fact that **space, in itself, is a human mind's construct that is used to differentiate between objects**. I'd hate for this to slip into the old _realism vs. idealism_ debate, so I'm not going to ask you to imagine space as an _objective truth_.
It must be noted that even though the mind receives a 2D image, it has ways of judging the **depth** and **distance** through it. Which is why a 2D object in reality would appear as a 2D object to us.

Comment: Einstein's theory holds little ground. As we now know, **'nothing' cannot exist in the universe**, which runs opposite to what he was proposing.

Comment: @Sampark Sharma To me the question of whether space is a human construct, or objective is hard and open. Attractive answer is that it is objective relative to us, that is it is something that emerges to beings of our constitution and perception from our particular way of interacting with the world, rather than a mental option. Objectivity proper is hard to defend because of "what does it mean and how would we know" questions, and a possibility that a different kind of beings could arrange their experience differently, with a space of different dimension, or even non-spatially.

Comment: What you say is rather interesting, especially so because recent findings, like those from the **double-slit experiment**, have made this theory much more plausible in the recent years. The idea of an **interactive reality** is an inviting one. Who knows, maybe there is a middle ground between _realism_ and _idealism_.

Answer (score 1):

"how would we be able to describe an object if we took out space from the mix?"

Surely the answer can only be in terms of ideas since most likely no one ever has seen an object without space.

So assuming an object can exist without space i would think its dimensionless and has the same substance like as example what you see when you close your eyes and imagine something.

On the other Hand i doubt what exists without space could not be called object.

Comment: Be careful now. Having always seen objects in context to their _spatial surroundings_, our brain cannot imagine something _without_ space. When I say the word **deer**, the first image that should pop into your mind is that of the animal. 
Doesn't the image in your head put the deer at the centre of space? You don't just imagine the deer, you _also_ imagine the space that is likely to surround it.

Comment: You dont imagine it without space but the imagination itself has no dimension so the deer you imagine is a deer which is in no space, it actually does not exist. However since you can still see it it somehow exists.

Comment: If I tell you to imagine a deer and _nothing else_, you would naturally remove the deer from what you take as its natural surroundings (say a forest) and put it in _blank space_. Though you think you are imagining the deer and nothing else, you are actually looking at it _through_ the context of space. Which means that space would have to be just as real as the deer.

Comment: I imagine a deer in the woods! Is the deer real because i imagine it? Are the Woods real because i imagine them? If they are not how can i see them? If they are in which kind of space does my Fantasy exist?

Comment: What you imagine _does not_ exist. And for all the things discussed on this thread, each of which is subject to much debate, this is something most Philosophers would agree on. Moreover, what you say here has nothing to do with what I'm asking. Why I asked you to _imagine_ them was to help you make better sense of my question. More likely than not, when you imagine this deer, you also imagine him surrounded by something. And what is it if not space?

Comment: Actually assuming you have a deer and you say you want it to be inside space, then a bubble of nonspace around it and around that again an obeserver inside space according to the answer to nelson?

Well i would say the space in which the observer is will fill the "Non-Space" around the object like a liquid and will create normal space. And in the short time between Light cannot pass the non-space nor can the observer anyhow interact with the object.
However the way i understood the question the way Nelson answered it and that one would make much more sense for me.

Comment: An other possibility would be that you get a wormhole in which the nonspace is not filled by space but does not seem to exist either you can just grab through it and it is as if there is no difference.
On the other hand you might find you grab on the other side of the universe. Also i Wonder how you come about a 2D object maybe your question is just terrible malformed so no one can decode it and you want to talk about taking a Dimension from the object?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you remove all the "space" or res extensa from an "object" you have a Euclidean point.

What does that mean? In what sense does this location without magnitude exist? It is, like zero, an  infinite placeholder that goes on somehow to engender more and more "places" (somewhat in the manner of Wallace Stevens' jar in Tennessee).

I would suggest (on no authority I can cite, though I am sure it is not at all original) that this axiomatic limit, vanishing point, or "point of origin" for the Euclidean system marks the existence of the geometer herself outside the plane, always one-dimension removed from the reference system under observation.

So what you get when you remove all the "space" from an object is as close as you can get to the unlimited context of that object, or the "transcendental subject."

Comment: I didn't ask you to remove all the _space/matter_ from an object, I asked you to remove it from _around_ it. Take the object to be a _truth_ and then remove everything you see in relation to it, including space. 

All the other Physics jargon is alien to me, and I cannot apprehend it. But I'm sure you now realise that you misinterpreted my question.

Comment: Okay, "out of the mix" wasn't clear to me, so not sure I grasp the question. A few thoughts: Leibniz argued against Newton that space is purely relational, so the idea of things "in space" is misleading. Intriguingly, there are branches of theoretical physics called "holographic principle" (Susskind) or "shape dynamics" (Barbour) with 2D mathematical models of the universe. Your descriptions sound very visual, which may prejudice you against ideas of temporal distinctions, as in Bergson. When we distinguish musical "objects" we do not "spatialize," except in theory after the fact.

Comment: More of a direct answer. Kant takes space and time to be absolute categories, prior to any experience or awareness of experience. So in the many Kantian-influenced philosophies-sciences, space is simply part of what we mean by "thinking." You "remove it" by... well, becoming unconscious. Your object, the glass of water, has become an irreducible "oneness" without even a "subject" to see it. So in a sense my earlier answer may have some relevance, even if we substitute "glass of water" for "point." The incoherence seems to arise from treating anything as an isolate or singularity.

Comment: And since *depth* is the mind's creation, a 2D model, at least of our very own world, would be an appropriate proposition. And as @Conifold pointed out in his answer, space just might be the mind's way of differentiating objects. Even Leibniz seems to have made a good argument, that I hope to read up on. The thing about Kant is that he talks in a very matter-of-fact way about a lot of things which are very important in the study of epistemology and metaphysics. Not something I'm fond of.